# Deferred jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, jquery-ajax

I've looked through all the issues on this, I think.

I have a function which uses jquery to update a record via ajax. I need to change it to do them and wait for each one to finish.

I've been reading about `$.Deferred` and have tried to implement, but the code still doesn't wait. I understand that ajax is asynchronous and I don't want to change that as such, but I do want it to wait, as the code outputs messages and I need them in order.

My code is as such:

```js
//do the export:
function doExport(id) {

var exportComplete = $.Deferred();

var exportPromise = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "import.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { id: id }
});

exportPromise.done(function(msg) {
    //msg contains the text from the import
    exportComplete.resolve(msg);
});

return exportComplete.promise();
}

//export all ticked items (from a list)
function importInvoices() {

    var checked = new Array;
    $('#apiCall').html("");

    //put all checked items into an array (id corresponds to a PK in the db)
    $("input[name=selectedRow]:checked").each(function(num,row) {
        checked.push($(row).data('id'));
    });

    //loop through each checked item
    $(checked).map(function(num, id) {
console.log("starting " + id)            ;
        var prom = doExport(id).then(function(result) {
console.log("done " + id);
            
            $('#apiCall').html($("#apiCall").html() + result.messages);
        
        });
    });

    $("#pleaseWaitContainer").hide();

}
```

It must be so close, but I guess I've got something missing or in the wrong place. The text from the resulting export does appear where it should, but if (for example) I select 3 invoices, I get the console text of "starting xxx" 3 times, and then the "done xxx" four times.

Like this:

```
starting 243
starting 663
starting 823
done 243
done 663
done 823
```

Whereas what I want is

```
starting 243
done 243
starting 663
done 663
starting 823
done 823
```

Any advise would be lovingly appreciated... I'm tearing my limited hair out.

Chris

Comment: Can't you just do the next one in the success of the Ajax?

Comment: Yeah, that is basically what I want to do. But all the examples I've seen have a set URL/function. Nothing dynamic I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call in Success

```js
const checked = $("input[name=selectedRow]:checked").map(function() {
  return $(this).data('id'))
}).get()
const load = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: `/someprocess.php?id=${checked.shift()}&otherparm=bla`,
    success: function() {
      if (checked.length > 0) load()
    }
  })
}

if (checked.length > 0) load(); // start
```

Comment: What's the `...` around the URL for?

Comment: You likely have `\`/somefolder/someprocess.php?id=${checked.shift()}&someotherparm=bla\``